# hibernate many to many must use flush () function to send it to database?

Tags: hibernate, ssh

For example
User user = new User (); Role role = new Role ("test"); HashSet  mList = new HashSet  (); user.setRoles (mList); userDao.save (user);
When userDao call transaction commit time, role can also automatically save. However. sql manytomany relationship between user and role must be submitted to the database before calling session.flush behind. I know that the content is stored in the session cache. But why must flush to submit? This is a mechanism to hibernate? Or that I saved the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing the session forces Hibernate to synchronize the in-memory state of the Session with the database (i.e. to write changes to the database). By default, Hibernate will flush changes automatically for you:

before some query executions
when a transaction is committed

When you explicitly use flush the Session gives finer control that may be required in some circumstances (to get an ID assigned, to control the size of the Session.

Comment: I find my mistake.Because I use the OpenSessionInViewFilter class so the flushMode of session is setting to FlushMode.MANUAL.  When I commit my transaction ,It dosen't flush changes automatically.Thanks for help